# Python preprocessor with rules to simplify class creation (domain specific language)

Tags: python, dsl, preprocessor

I'm building something between a Python library and a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (domain specific language), for very specific applications, such that we can avoid:

```
class Car(RoomObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = rect(-20, -20, 40, 40)
        self.zindex = -10
        self.pos = self.rect.midbottom  
        _tempvar = 123
    def do(self, x)
        self.foo = x
```

and have this instead:

```
class Car(RoomObject):  # 1) avoid the def and self, all nested paragraphs in class are def 
    init():             # 2) __init__ -> init        3) automatically do the super init
        rect = rect(-20, -20, 40, 40)  # 4) assignations are self. by default...
        zindex = -10
        pos = rect.midbottom  
        _tempvar = 123                 # 5) ...except if variable name begins with _
    do(x):                             # ==> def do(self, x):
        foo = x                        # ==> self.foo = x
```

**Can this be done with a built-in Python library, such as `inspect` (code introspection) or a preprocessor (if any), or not?**

---

Context: it's for a niche market, where I can't ask non-tech people to write things like `def __init__(self):` `super().__init__()` `self.rect = ...` all the time. I need those specific people to be able to write in a simpler dialect, and my tool translate it into regular Python.

Comment: no, `inspect` won't really help you here. It looks like you want to create *another language*. Python doesn't have a pre-processor. You coudl, of course, write code to parse this source code and generate some equivalent python code... sounds like a fairly serious project. ... it seems like *a loooot* of work when you could just... write python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I added more context at the end of the question.

Comment: Right, well, then you have to write a parser and something that generates the code from the output of that parser, basically, a transpiler. To get that parsing, you would probably want to use tools like lex and yacc.. or maybe `pyparsing`. This question is really too braod, like I said, this is quite the project. Of course, you don't need any external libraries, but writing that all from scratch in Python would be a pretty monumental task.

Comment: I think your 2 comments are the answer (feel free to post it, I'll accept it).

Comment: @Basj if you need non-tech people to write information that becomes Python later on, isn't it easier to give them a structure to write the information into? A GUI, a JSON file, even an Excel spreadsheet if they're that "averse" to code. Some sort of default structure that you later on parse and convert to Python objects.

Comment: @jfaccioni Well it's really sitting somewhere in between just "data" (that could be stored in JSON or Excel or CSV) and code (I need them to have `if` conditions, `for` loops etc.). I would like to be able to edit their "dialect code" and add some normal Python code myself if needed, etc.

Comment: @Basj -- This page -- [Easy Forth](https://skilldrick.github.io/easyforth/) -- implements one of my favorite languages in JavaScript.  It's a favorite because it is so simple to implement that it used to be a rite of passage, and used to be some of the first code used to boot up a new processor.  But it is also a high level language because it easily implements DSL's.  If you go through this tutorial, you'll see a DSL controlling a small snake game, a command-line interface, and more.  View source on the page, and you'll see that it's modular, implemented in different files.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The Forth language can also be considered a VM construction kit, though I've never heard anybody else call it that.  The JVM and .NET CIL are VM's built with stack languages, and that's what Forth is.  A different flavored alternative, which is excellent, is [Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_(programming_language)), but I digress.  Excellent -- [Factor: an extensible interactive language](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_0QlhYlS8g).  To learn DSL's, I study languages. Some of the most powerful machines are built with the simplest of mechanisms -- also true of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write a dialect.

You can do this to some extent, see the implementation of https://pypi.org/project/pypreprocessor/.

You can write something like:

```py
import mypreprocessor
mypreprocessor.parse()

class Car(RoomObject):  # 1) avoid the def and self, all nested paragraphs in class are def 
    init():             # 2) __init__ -> init        3) automatically do the super init
        rect = rect(-20, -20, 40, 40)  # 4) assignations are self. by default...
        zindex = -10
        pos = rect.midbottom  
        _tempvar = 123                 # 5) ...except if variable name begins with _
    do(x):                             # ==> def do(self, x):
        foo = x                        # ==> self.foo = x
```

Then in `mypreprocessor.parse()`:

```py
def parse():
    ... load current file
    ... preprocess
    ... call exec()
    ... sys.exit(0)
```